# When do I have to stop a Service manually?

Tags: android

I have a class SendMessageService which extends from Service. This class sends chat messages to the server in the background. 
Do I **always** have to call [`stopSelf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf(int)) when I return from my service?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent == null || !AppUtil.hasInternetConnection(this)) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    startID = startId;

    handler = new Handler();
    messageDatabase = MessageDatabase.getInstance(this);

    sendMessages();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Do I have to call `stopself()` above `return START_STICKY`?

```
private void sendMessages() {
    // get all unsend messages
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                final ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
                messageDatabase.getConditionBuilder().add(DatabaseHelper.KEY_MESSAGE_SENT + " = ?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(0) });
                messageDatabase.getConditionBuilder().setSortOrder(DatabaseHelper.KEY_MESSAGE_LOCAL_TIME + " ASC");
                messages.addAll(messageDatabase.getList());

                // ...
                sendMessageRecursive(0, messages);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private void sendMessageRecursive(final int index, final ArrayList<Message> messages) {
    if (index >= messages.size()) {
        stopSelf(startID);
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Do I have to call `stopSelf()` in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I always have to call stopSelf() when I return from my service?

You call `stopSelf()` (or `stopService()` from outside the service) when you no longer want the service to be running. Do not just toss code into a `Service` without a very clear plan for when that service should and should not be running. [Only have a service running when it is **actively delivering value to the user**](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

In this case, I'm not quite certain why you didn't choose `IntentService`, considering that it handles your threading and "do I need to stop?" issues for you.

That being said, given your existing code, and assuming that there's nothing else to the service than what you have shown here, you should call `stopSelf()`:

- In `onStartCommand()` if you're not actually going to be doing any work (as you are then not actively delivering value to the user), rather than return `START_STICKY`
- At the end of `run()`, when you are doing doing the work (and therefore will no longer be actively delivering value to the user)